# Class loading from a non-default Package

Tags: java, dynamic, package, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

When I try to load a class Dynamically at run-time, and that class was compiled in a package that is not the default package, I have a ClassNotFound Exception.

Example:
Package name: "Model".
Class name: "Cup.class".
This is my code:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
            URL url;
            URL[] urls;
            String name = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length()-6);
            file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(file.getName(), ""));
            System.out.println(name);
            // Convert File to a URL
            url = file.toURL();
            urls = new URL[]{url};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);          
            Class cls = cl.loadClass(name);     
            Shape temp = (Shape) cls.newInstance();
            ShapeFactory.getInstance().registerShape(temp);
```

Comment: But Cup is the class I'm wanting to load, it extends Shape,
Should it be then: ClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(url, Shape.class.getClassLoader()); 
?

Comment: This is the exception I get:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Cup (wrong name: Model/Cup)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Model.Cup

Comment: Yes, I tried to put the class in a Folder names "Model" and then load it the same way, and it worked.
Thank you very much.